# Highlight a line with different color in Parallel coordinate chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, highcharts, parallel-coordinates

I wanted to a represent a line with different color which will show some special behaviour. In this [example](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/parallel-coordinates) blue lines shows a normal data but I wanted to annotate a single line with red line. Is there any way to do this .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some condition to highlight a specific series:

```
        series: data.map(function (set, i) {
            if (i === 10) {
                return {
                    name: 'Runner ' + i,
                    data: set,
                    shadow: false,
                    color: 'red',
                    zIndex: 1
                };
            }
            return {
                name: 'Runner ' + i,
                data: set,
                shadow: false
            };
        })
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/17m3waLu/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. It worked but showing only half line color as red.

Comment: Hi Pratik Rawlekar, the whole line should be red. Could you provide me with some image?

Comment: When I hover on other lines this red line partially disappears. We can say it gets hide behind the other hovered lines. How can we keep this red line always visible .?

Comment: Hi Pratik Rawlekar, you probably have not added `this.group.toFront();` in series `mouseOver` event.

Comment: I have added this which takes hovered line up front but this red coloured annotation line gets hidden behind other lines.

Comment: Have look at this example [ https://jsfiddle.net/pratikrawlekar/ceukrn75/4/ ]. When you hover on other line yellow line gets hide.

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. You need to call `toFront` on the yellow line on each `mouseover`: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/t78mdjkw/